# Core Graphics caching

Tags: ios, core-graphics

When loading images into the app with `[UIImage imageNamed: fileName]`, the system caches the images and therefore provides a performance boost when the same image is used again.

Is there something similar for images created with Core Graphics? I mean images created from contexts with the `UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();` method.

The current approach I have is to draw the image and save the UIImage to disk, so that next time I need to use the same drawing method I can simply load the cached image from disk. I'm looking for a better way to store Core Graphics generated images as the current approach seems cumbersome.

Maybe even store the CGContextRef with all the drawing in some caching data-structure, I'm not quite sure if that's possible?

My aim is to use only Core Graphics so my app bundle is smaller and I get resolution independence, but I'd like to improve the performance as complicated drawing routines can take a lot of time to process.

UPDATE: After doing some performance testing here are my results. Each time is an average over 100 runs, either drawing 19 or 25 different views at a time. Views included, rectangles, circles, but also text as UILabels. Fills, strokes, gradients and shadows were used.

Caching was implemented as discussed in the answer, with a NSDictionary storing the UIImage objects. Every run had an individual cache, which was used within the run, but not for all the views (out of 25, there were 2 sets of 8, 2 sets of 6 out of 19, which were identical and could be cached).

Here are the times: 
**iOS Simulator**

**19 views**

No caching - average run 11.667ms

Caching - average run 10.321ms

**25 views**

No caching - average run 14.304ms

Caching - average run 13.509ms

**Device**

**19 views**

No caching - average 82.785ms
Caching - average 77.831ms

**25 views**

No caching - average 107.977ms
Caching - average 100.094ms

There is a remarkable difference (almost 8%) between the times and when accounting for the longer first time (to save to cache) it would still be beneficial to use the cache.

Comment: Do you mean store within a single session or store between launches of the app? Much better question this time btw :)

Comment: Both are interesting, but I guess a single session solution would make more sense (I'm trying to use as little of actual storage space as possible, hence getting rid of images as assets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've no performance data to back this up but I think the UIImage caching when using imageNamed is to save reading the file from "disk" and converting the png or whatever to UIImage data.

Therefore your approach of writing to disk would seem to be an unnecessary step - once you have your UIImage object, this is as optimised as you are going to get.

You could consider something like an image "factory" singleton which lazily creates images as they are requested - so the first time, it would do the requisite core graphics operations to create the UIImage, and thereafter return the completed object. Each different image would just be stored as an ivar in your factory.

Comment: OK, but what if my drawing methods are a bit more dynamic and can change certain aspects of the drawing, how would I be able to differentiate different versions of the images? I'm thinking about using a NSDictionary with keys being NSDictionaries representing the configuration of the image and the values would then be the UIImage objects, would this make any sense?

Comment: It's difficult to say without knowing what you're doing. The first thing would be to make sure that you actually have a peformance problem to deal with, before introducing all this complexity, if so then yes your approach makes sense - you could perhaps mix the two and have unvarying parts in UIImage objects then draw your varying parts in real time, but its hard without specifics.

Comment: Basically I have a set of drawing methods for primitives, like rectangles or ellipses, these take in variables to change color, stroking, shadowing etc of the elements. At this time there is no real performance "issue", but I want to use the graphics in situations like tableviews where there will be 20+ of them created rapidly and some may look exactly the same... Anyway, I'm hoping someone has some performance numbers about UIImage caching.

Comment: I'll do some performance tests and accept this answer later, unless there is something better posted by then :)

Comment: Fully understood! Remember you also get caching in the tableView. I fully support your drawing in code approach too (mostly because I can't draw to save my life!)

Comment: TableView caches the cells, but not its' content, am I right? So if for example I change the image in every cell, then I won't get the caching, but if the cell itself uses CG for its' drawing then I do get that boost.
For me it's not really about drawing, more about ways to save space and future-proofing my apps + I don't like the current "have two sets of every asset" approach Apple suggests.

Comment: Yes, no caching if the image is different in every cell.

Comment: Accepted the answer, added performance test results to the question.